# Orika - ParameterNamesNotFoundException: One or more @Named annotations missing for class

Tags: orika

I am getting the following exception in Orika

```
ParameterNamesNotFoundException: One or more @Named annotations missing for class
```

I have 2 simple pojos and I want to map them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your pojo  class declarations to outter classes. Orika cannot handle inner classes.